# Can the site owner browse the site in Viewer's view?

Tags: permissions, security-trimming, roles

We are using SP2013 on-premise. On a site collection we have some both public content and sensitive content. Viewers do not have permission on sensitive contents.

The site owner (who have full control permission on the site) would like to review the site from Viewer's angle to make sure sensitive contents are not shown.

Beside change his permission to viewer or asking a viewer (another user) to check, how can he achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site owner can not view site from **Viewer's** angle. Your given permission must be appeared whenever you login in a site.

When I test permission in sites, I used to create several users like Editor, Reader, Admin and so on.

Answer (score 1):

OOTB he can't, the best option is to have a test account(s) for this purpose where you can log into a PC or run browser sessions as that dedicated test account and get the same experience as the other users. He only has the option to go through lists and libraries looking for broken permissions and doing effective permission lookups.